# iOS Google analytics size increase?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, google-analytics-api

I've just upgraded to the latest version of Google Analytics, and I noticed the size of `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a` has increased from 5.3 mb to 10.3 mb! I also noticed there is some new tag feature and I'm wondering if this is what's causing the increase. Is it possible to remove this feature and get the size back down to 5.3 mb? Obviously the extra 5 mb is undesirable because it adds a lot the binary size of my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe they've started supporting Arm64. If it is due to extra architectures, the link phase will strip out any that your app isn't using. Have you checked if there actually is an increase in your binary size?

Comment: You're exactly right, this release does bring support for 64 bit. When I produce an archive and estimate the size of the binary, it's not stripping out the unnecessary files.

Comment: It really ought to go down, 2/5 of the file is simulator architectures. What are you building? armv7 + armv7s + arm64?

Comment: Yes, arm64 armv7 armv7s. I'm supporting iOS6 and above. Do I need all of these?

Comment: If size is a priority and performance is not you could strip it back to just armv7 as that runs on the other two architectures.

Comment: Nah I need performance, 5 mb I guess isn't that big in the scheme of things. Thanks for helping me realize though what was causing it. I thought maybe I was including some stuff I didn't need.